# JQuery UI Sortable Disable Update function before receive

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jquery ui to process a list that you can sort within and then also sort between another list.  I'm using the update for the sorting within and that works fine.  When I sort between I just want to call the receive function and not the update.  Currently, update gets called and then receive gets called.   Is there any way to skip the update call when sorting between lists?

```
<script>
            $ = jQuery
            $(function() {
                $( "#sortable1).sortable({
                    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
                    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
                    update: function(event, ui) {processSortWithin(ui.item.attr("id"), ui.item.index()); },
                    receive: function(event, ui){ 
                        processSortBetween(ui.item.attr("id"), ui.item.index(),ui.sender.attr("id"));
                    }
                }).disableSelection();
            });

        </script>
```

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking for, but you might consider using stop instead.  See this SO question for more information and a very nice link to explanation of exactly which events get called in what order: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963822/jquery-sortable-events-being-called-too-many-times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Answer from: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/sortables-update-callback-and-connectwith

```
update: function(e,ui) {
    if (this === ui.item.parent()[0]) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: This will distinguish between sorting within the list and removing an element from the list but won't distinguish between sorting within the list and receiving an item from another list.  To do that you need a combination of this answer and @MarkN's answer, `if (!ui.sender && this === ui.item.parent()[0]) { /* Sort within list ... */ }`

Comment: this works, for some reason the ui.sender attribute is always null in the case where there are two linked lists and a recieve, remove, and stop events. go figure.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem today, and the only solution I found was to introduce a flag variable that is set during *update* event, and checked during *stop* event.

In your example, you use *receive* event which will be fired on the list that receives new element from some other list, so it should be set inside `$(".connectedSortable").sortable()` options.

Here is my way to distinguish whether to sort (within one list, processed in *stop*) or to move (between two lists, processed in *receive*):

```
$(function() {
    position_updated = false; //helper flag for sortable below

    $(".sortable").sortable({
        connectWith: ".sortable",
        update: function(event, ui) {
            position_updated = !ui.sender; //if no sender, set sortWithin flag to true
        },
        stop: function(event, ui) {
            if (position_updated) {
                processSortWithin(ui.item.attr("id"), ui.item.index());
                position_updated = false;
            }
        },
        receive: function(event, ui) {
            processSortBetween(ui.item.attr("id"), ui.item.index(),ui.sender.attr("id"));
        }
    }).disableSelection();
});

function processSortWithin(id, position) {
    alert("sort within");
}

function processSortBetween(id, position, sender_id) {
    alert("sort between");
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/myLff/2/

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
update: function(e,ui) {
   if (!ui.sender) {
       //your code here
   }
}
```