# Using JQuery Sortable toArray with connectWith; how to get IDs of all items?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Given *n* lists of *m* items that are Sortable across lists, how can I get an overall list of IDs for all items in all lists from top to bottom (including both sort participants and non-participants)?

My list of items looks something like this:

```
Category 1
- (id=a) Item 1A
- (id=b) Item 1B
Category 2
- (id=c) Item 2A
- (id=d) Item 2B
Category 3
- (id=e) Item 3A
- (id=f) Item 3B
```

These items are `Sortable` across categories and connected via `connectWith` (see below for code).  Item 2B, for example, may be dragged and dropped into Category 1.

I can get as far as using `update` and `toArray` to get IDs for the section being dragged from and the section being dragged to, but is there a clean way to access all of them?  Do I need to build it manually somehow? **How can I get a list of *all* the IDs in their current sort order?**

If I drag Item 2B to the first position in Category 1, for example, I can get two array lists for two fires of the `update`, the first containing "d" (the list I moved from) and the second containing "c, a, b" (the list I moved to).  How can I get a list containing "c, a, b, d, e, f"?  This is happening on a button click, so I'm not restricted to `update`, if there's a better mechanism through which to get the information.

[Here's a JFIDDLE demo](http://jsfiddle.net/a7QA3/) of what I have so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a native function to do this, so I [**created a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6EKay/1/) that iterates all the `.sortable` elements to create one array and log to the console in Chrome or Firefox with Firebug. I also changed the `update` to `receive` so it only fires once (see [jQueryUI sortable documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/)).

Comment: Not native, but still much simpler than I was trying to make it. Extra +1s (if they were legal) for JSFIDDLE and Firebug.  Many thanks!

Comment: Minor problem with receive, though -- it's triggered for inter-list sorting only.  An intra-list move (e.g., Item 2 to position 1 in your demo) doesn't trigger it.  Looks like I'm back to update.  The double-firing isn't ideal, but it's workable enough in my actual project. :)

Comment: Stop seems to be the one I want, actually. More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/963822/jquery-sortable-events-being-called-too-many-times.

Comment: Yes, `stop()` is correct. Fired at the end of either an internal or connected list sorting. Nice investigation :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to just loop through all the sortable child elements and record their order.

```
$('.sortable').sortable({ 
    items: '> tr.child',
    connectWith: $('tbody'),
    receive: function(event, ui) {
        var myOrder = new Array();
        $(".sortable tr.child").each(function() {
            myOrder.push($(this).attr("id"));
        });
        console.log(myOrder.toString());  
    }
});
```

This has the added benefit of allowing adding and deleting sortable containers at any time -- this script will work regardless.